# Prototype mismatch: sub main::strftime

Tags: perl, unix-timestamp, strftime

In my perl program am using `use POSIX qw( strftime );` library to perform unixtimestamp to date conversion as follows,

```
my $dt = strftime("%m/%d/%y", localtime($fields[0]));
```

Conversion is happening as expected but am getting the following error.

```
 Prototype mismatch: sub main::strftime ($\@;$) vs none at 
 /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.5/Exporter.pm line 67.
 at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/POSIX.pm line 19
```

Has anyone guide me what is the reason and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You either have two functions named `strftime` (but then you would probably have another warning too), or you used `strftime` before it was declared.

---

I always specify my imports explicitly, so I never run into the first problem.

```
 use Date::Format qw( );
 use POSIX        qw( strftime );
```

Comment: At the top of the script I have used "use POSIX qw( strftime )" library and in the middle of the script I have used "strftime" function.

Comment: As you said I have used "use Date::Parse;
use Date::Format" libraries also.. Is it a problem?

Comment: yeah thanks man. I have used use Date::Parse; use Date::Format which is not at all necessary. I have commented them and error went off.

Comment: If you'd put a 'use warnings' at the top of your code you'd have got a more understandable warning that `strftime` was being redeclared. Basically `Date::Format` is also exporting a method called `strftime`.  This is why it's often good practice to use EXPORT_OK not EXPORT and force the user to say which methods they want to import.

Comment: yeah @plusplus. thats true. thatnks for your feedback. I will use warnings as well.

Comment: `use strict` and `use warnings` are pretty much essential everywhere. They seem annoying at first, but catch so many typos and strange errors and will save you *so* much time in the long run.

Comment: @plusplus use warnings does *not* add anything; it is lexical in scope, and the redefinition occurs in Exporter, outside the scope.  -w will give a redefinition warning.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same error when I **used a function before its been declare/defined**.
Although there can be more reasons since answer is already accepted, this may help someone.

```
sub func1{
 func2();
}

sub func2{
}
```

solution was simply to move **func2** before **func1**.

```
sub func2{
}

sub func1{
 func2();
}
```